# What is the meaning of the ≼ Symbol in the Context of Matrix Inequality with Symmetric Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, linear-matrix-inequality

I saw the symbol ≼ in a textbook, and I am not quite sure what it means. The textbook says it represents matrix inequality, but again, I do not understand what that means. My best guesses are that the matrix on the left of the inequality has a lower determinant or that each element is lower, but I am just guessing. Please let me know what this symbol means in this context. Thanks.[image]

Comment: I would guess that $A≼ B$ if $B-A$ is positive semi-definite

Comment: So would this mean that the bowl formed by the energy of B is stronger convex than the bowl formed by the energy of A?

Comment: I don't know what *that* means!

Comment: It is a test of positive definiteness. The energy of A would be x^T*A*x, where x is the vector containing the independent variables. So if A were 2x2 then x would be x=(x, y) and the parabola created would be in 3D space.

Comment: I have no idea what "the energy of $A$" is, but this notation does mean exactly what Calvin says, and you are right that it means that $B$ defines a "more convex" quadratic function in the sense that its strong convexity constant is larger.

Comment: @JackN To be more precise, it seems as though the "bowl" you're referring to is the graph $z = \mathbf x^T A \mathbf x$

Answer (score 1):

To connect the given inequality to the discussion in the comments, the condition $m I \preceq A \preceq M I$ holds if and only if for all $y \in \mathbf  R^n$, we have
$$
m\cdot y^Ty = y^T(mI)y \leq y^TAy \leq y^T(MI)y = M \cdot y^Ty.
$$
For a graphical interpretation, the $(n+1)$-dimensional graph $z = x^TAx$ (with $z$ as the "vertical" direction) lies above the graph $z = m\cdot x^Tx$ and below the graph $z = M\cdot x^Tx$.